# Angular2 table model binding with text input

Tags: angular, binding, angular2-ngmodel

I have a PrimeNG table which cells are editable. When I edit the value of the input text field the table model does not change. How do I make the table model bind to the input text?

Here is my code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [editable]="true">
    <p-column>
        <template pTemplate type="body" let-row="rowData">
            <custom-input [(inputModel)]="row.value"></custom-input>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

custom-input.html

```
<input #inputText pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputModel" />
```

custom-input.ts

```
export class ValidationInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() inputModel: Object;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are having an external custom-input.html? I do not know if it helps, but you could try to write the `<input>` directly instead of referring to another html file.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without the external custom component everything works fine. But I want to have a custom component, because it has some other css features unlike the normal input field. And it so often used in my project.

Comment: What do you mean by *table model does not change* ? :)

Comment: For example, I have some values, let say A, B, C (3 rows). And I change/edit the first one to ABC (A->ABC).
Then when I click to save, it doesn't save (ABC, B, C) but (A, B, C) - the old values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit the values to your parent, parent won't get the notification for change automatically. You need to use `Output` for this purpose.

So in your child, do this:

```
<input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputModel" (ngModelChange)="emitChange()" />
```

Where we call a method when changes are made on the input. That method then emits the change to the parent.

```
@Output() inputModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

emitChange() {
  this.inputModelChange.emit(this.inputModel)
}
```

For two-way binding we use the same `inputModel` as in declared as Input, but just add the suffix `Change`, this means that the values in parent and child will be matched.

and here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iBZGOlQa6TbaiSN3VXdl?p=preview)

Comment: myanmar, did this answer, or the other answer help? If so, please consider accepting one :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `row.value` to your `inputModel`, pass the whole `row` instead:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [editable]="true">
    <p-column>
        <template pTemplate type="body" let-row="rowData">
            <custom-input [(inputModel)]="row"></custom-input>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Then, instead of setting `[(ngModel)]` to `inputModel` in your custom template, set it to `inputModel.value`.

```
<input #inputText pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputModel.value" />
```

Here is an [Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-binding-text) illustrating that the input binds to the title using a custom component.

The reason this works is because `row.value` is probably a primitive (e.g. string, number, or boolean), and you cannot two-way-bind a primitive, only objects. (eg. `var row:any = {value:"some value"}`). 
Your `custom-input` takes in the whole object (the `row`), and manipulates the `value` property on it.

**EDIT:**

Removed <s>[Example Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/y5UMoHQk0uM93IG9Er90?)</s> because the example did not load. Added new example in Stackblitz instead.

Comment: The example doesn't exist

Comment: Seems like the plunkr is not loading. I will create a new one in Stackblitz tomorrow. Thanks for informing

Comment: @Waqas I added a working example now. Thanks again for letting me know.